# Java generics, a way to enforce either super or subtype

Tags: java, generics

Assume I have a class and a method such as this:

```
class MyClass<T> {

    void doStuff(Wrapper<T> wrapper) {
        //impl.
    }
}
```

Generic bounds of the parameter "wrapper" can be modified to `Wrapper<? extends T>` to make the method accept subtypes of T, and `Wrapper<? super T>` to accept super types. However, is there a way to modify MyClass such that it accepts both sub and super types of T (not any type), and there is only one method name? (there can be overloads)

I could simply go with `Wrapper<?>` of course, but "accept anything" is not the same as "accept something that's in the class hierarchy for T". I could also make 2 separate methods, one with `<? super T>` and one with `<? extends T>`, but then these methods would need different names, since the signature is the same after erasure.

Note: Please consider this a question out of curiosity.

Comment: It's an interesting question in the abstract, but I'm having trouble seeing how the type information you would have in such a case would be useful for anything in type-safe code.

Comment: Yes, I'm not quite sure how this would work. Imagine you had the syntax: List<<T extends BaseClass | super ChildClass>>. Then, to the code inside that method faced with the question "can I assign an object from that list to a reference of such-and-such a class", the answer would be "maybe I can, maybe I can't".

Comment: @JohnBollinger I understand its a bit messy. I will try to clear it up a bit. Assume my class is a generic Collection<T> and I have a class hierarchy of A->B->C. Wrapper<T> is something like Prop<T>, a known property of a class that is known ahead of time (through codeden). And the method is filter(Prop<T>, V value). A Collection<A> could contain As, Bs and Cs, and it should be valid to filter this by Prop<B>, you could end up with Bs and Cs, since A does not have Prop<B>. On the other hand a Collection<C> should be filterable by Prop<A> since C is a subtype of A and has that property. Cont.

Comment: @NeilCoffey (Continuing the prev. comment) . A Collection<C> should not be able to be filtered by Prop<X> though, that's not allowed and there should be a compile time error. This is actually a public API of sorts where I want compile time errors (and why I need a single method), ugly type checking/handling i s unavoidable inside it. I do understand that this is not the best design, or even good design, but it's what I ended up needing with my current design and aside from that, seemed to be a nice theoretical question.

Comment: @sydnal, I think I see the idea you are describing, but my point is that I don't think that what you have actually asked about would provide a type-safe way to implement it.  Remember that Java generics are essentially *compile-time* testable type constraints and assertions.  Type parameters cannot be evaluated at runtime, as would be necessary to apply the kind of filtering you describe.

Comment: Nor, for that matter, is it clear to me why the specific application you describe would even rely on what you asked for.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I do have the actual type info at runtime, embedded as a Class<?> field somewhere in there through codegen, which I can use to do - dirty - type checking. As for the second comment, I can't argue against this being messy and convoluted. Anyway, the design is not important, can change or be scrapped altogether, but the question itself, abstracted from the implementation, seemed interesting enough even if it may not be useful at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the following

```
<S extends T> void doStuff(Wrapper<? super S> wrapper)
```

but would need to double check this satisfies your requirements.

Comment: Great, that works. It looks deceptively simple, but it didn't even cross my mind. Thanks.